# Debugging native apps on Android, with GDB

Tags: android, debugging, gdb

I'd like to debug a native application for Android, like, for example, the standard browser app. How can I do that, with GDB (or any other debugger). I would prefer a solution for a real device, not an emulator, but the latter is fine too, if the first option is too complicated/impossible (?). Android version I'm interested in is 2.3.4 (latest).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to get the source of the application and build/debug it just like any other app.
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Browser